# Using default sql tables to find columns present in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database set up with clients data split by schema.

Within sql I would like to identify for the table products which columns containing the string "id" exist

I'm trying to use the pg_... tables to identify these columns, but the below query appears to be bringing back results from across schemas despite the restriction on table_schema

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_class c
  INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
  INNER JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
  INNER JOIN information_schema.tables sch ON c.relname = sch.table_name
WHERE c.relname = 'products'
AND   a.attnum > 0
AND   a.attname LIKE '%id%'
AND   table_schema = 'schema001'
```

I guess the schemas could be set up incorrectly or the where clause is incorrect - any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pg_namespace and drop the information_schema:

```
SELECT nspname, relname, attname
FROM pg_class c
  INNER JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
  INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
  INNER JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
WHERE c.relname = 'products'
AND   a.attnum > 0
AND   a.attname LIKE '%id%'
AND   n.nspname = 'schema001';
```

Comment: thankyou works great! Do you know where I could find some documentation regarding these tables? As they are very handy but difficult  to interpret

Comment: They are part of the system catalog: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalogs.html